# When i am adding products to cart from website they are not shown in web application

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.6

In Magento2 When I'm adding products in cart from website they are not shown in web application. I'm using magento rest API in react-native application.

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: are you adding products from website or from mobile application? clear it. you are saying you are adding from web and then you are putting about react native app.

Comment: adding products from website. but the products that i added are not shown in application.

Comment: have to logged in to web before adding product to cart and make sure you have logged in with same customer on app as well.

Comment: yes i logged in to website and added to cart and logged in with same user in application

Comment: can  you paste here the response of api request.

Comment: Since with their rest api they have some limitation and while pulling and sending data from web to mob and so forth, you can create your custom api's which don't require rest or soap api, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240403/how-to-create-an-rest-api-in-magento-2/240633#240633