# catalog price rules prices in web api for mobile apps

Tags: magento2

We have created a catalog price rule for a group of customers. The discounted prices are showing fine on website for these customers.

However, these discounted prices are not showing up when we search products or get category listings via Magento's default api calls.

How can we get these prices? Do we need to customize?

Thanks

Comment: are you using rest api or custom build one?

Comment: its default rest api

Comment: that's because you haven't set the customer group id while making rest api request for search products or catalog listing. set customer group id as per customer status and you will get discounted price as set for that group of customer.

Comment: @John thanks. But then do I need to use customer token or same admin token would work?

Comment: yes you need current customer token, admin token is out of scope for this scenario.

Comment: I am not sure. Never tried it but would these default api work with customer token? I have always used them with Admin tokens. Thanks anyway @John. Your response was much appreciated.

Comment: it depends on type of api you are calling and type of parameter its accepting. You can call two api here, one is to call customer group types to check their discount price and next one is to check current customer group id and show him the price based on their group. Also, in my experience current api's are limited, that's why i always go with custom api's. Check this out. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240403/how-to-create-an-rest-api-in-magento-2/240633#240633